# What is the meaning of the matrices over the arrows in a free resolution?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am reading [the lecture notes](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~takumim/hilbertpresentation.pdf). I have a simple question about free resolution.

What is the meaning of the matrices over the arrows in a free resolution? For example, the matrices in the following free resolution.

\begin{align}
0 \to S^2(-3) \overset{\left( \begin{matrix} x_0 & x_1 \\ x_1 & x_2 \\ x_2 & x_3 \end{matrix} \right)}{\to} S^3(-2) \overset{( x_1 x_3 - x_2^2 \ -x_0x_3 + x_1 x_2 \ x_0x_2 - x_1^2  )}{\to} S.
\end{align}

I have not take the course of algebraic geometry before. So it would be great if the answers are in detail. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: They usually just define the maps between your free modules.

Comment: An element of $S^2(-3)$ (or $S(-3)^{\oplus 2}$, as I usually write it), is a $2 \times 1$ column vector of elements of $S(-3)$. Left multiplication by this $3 \times 2$ matrix maps such a vector to a $3 \times 1$ vector of elements of $S(-2)$.

Comment: @André3000, thank you very much. What are the basis of $S(-3)$ and $S(-2)$?

Comment: @LJR I don't quite know how to explain... $S(−3)$ is isomorphic to $S$ (i.e., is a free $S$-module of rank $1$) but with generator in degree 3. You might want to look at Eisenbud's commutative algebra book, as referenced in the notes you linked.

Comment: @Andre 3000, thank you very much.