# How to understand the notation $S(-3)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I asked [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3078732/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-matrices-over-the-arrows-in-a-free-resolution) about linear maps between free modules. I have a related question.

Let $S=k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ where $k$ is a field. Then $S$ is a graded ring with usual grading given by $\deg x_i = 1$. By definition, $S(a)$ is a graded module defined by $S(a)_d = S_{a+d}$. What is the basis of $S(a)$? For example, what is the basis of $S(-3)$?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The basis of $S(a)$ is formed by all monomials $x^i = x_1^{i_1}\cdots x_n^{i_n}$, but the degree of $x^i$ is equal to $i_1 + \dots + i_n - a$.

Comment: This is a basis as a $k$-vector space, right? Because as an $S$-module, $S(a)$ has rank $1$.

Comment: Sure. As an $S$-module the basis is given by one element (monomial 1) in degree $-a$.